# How to make a client for a site that handles logins with Facebook?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a client in NodeJS that is meant to replace using a website, and it isn't my website. It uses Facebook to log in. Is it possible to log in via a Facebook username/password? It seems modules like passport-facebook are intended for use with a website that you own, which is not the case in my scenario.

I suspect that I can't login with a username and password, so I'd have to sniff web traffic of me browsing the normal website for my token for the website, and then somehow use that in Node, but I hope this isn't the case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, users can not login by entering their FB credentials on _your_ site. In fact, apps are explicitly forbidden from asking users for those. You need to implement the OAuth login flow.

Comment: Right, I got that they can't enter their creds on my site. That would be a huge security risk since I could intercept it. So I can use something like passport-facebook to implement an oauth thing? How would I do that?

Comment: Yes, passport-facebook would be one way to achieve that. How that works and how to set it up, should be in the module documentation.